# Can I get rid of SVN in my Xcode project?

Tags: xcode, svn

I have problems with subversion in my Xcode project, and I would therefore like to get rid of its and keep the local copy of all files.  How can I do this?

(I have been thinking of deleting all .svn directories but I guess I also have to tell Xcode to skip svn)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, i was confused with your question. You want to get rid of your repository or you just want to get rid of subversion for your xcode project.

1 - **Well, you can show / hide the repositories from your xcode project or else you can delete the repositories from the pane in the Organizer window**

[image]

2 -

> **svn delete --keep-local the_file**

Comment: When I build the project I get a lot of warnings because some files are missing. But they are not missing from the project only from the repository. Usually I solve this kind of problem by an "svn update", but this time svn complains and says that I must do a "cleanup" first. I have tried it, but am not allowed to do that either.